# How do ultrasonic range behave with two objects at differents distance?

Tags: arduino, sensors, ultrasonic-sensors

If I have the following objects: A and B. A is a distance "Y" from the ultrasonic sense and B is a distance "x".
If B is fix and A is moving, does the ultrasonic sense receive and detects A distance?

[image: Ultrasonic sense and positions of objects]

Comment: There are a number of factors that may affect this, but typically one sensor is going to *ping* off whichever obstacle is closest. You could use IR proximity sensors which are likely to have a narrower *beam*.

Comment: [The answer to this related question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2341/how-do-ultrasonic-range-finders-detect-objects-at-an-angle?rq=1) may have some helpful information for your situation.

Comment: This is also dependent on what ultrasonic sensor you use. From a theory perspective you could send a chirp and receive both responses superimposed on each other. This could be processed out to get the individual object distances. This however isn't how most low end hobby ultrasonics work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap ultrasonic sensors will give you a signal when the first echo (from the closest object) is received. Hence, you'll get a reading of 'X' for object B, and probably nothing for the object A, no matter if it's moving or not.

Which makes sense, because if you keep moving in the current direction, object B is the one you should be most concerned about.